# install a windows 7 .msi for all present and future users

Tags: windows-installer

If I create a .msi installer and install at the command line with:

> msiexec /i foo.msi ALLUSERS=1

I've installed foo for all users. If I then create a new user on the system
then I try to run foo from the start menu, Windows 7 will try to install the
foo package for that user. If the .msi file isn't around. it fails. Is there
a way to install this package for all present AND future users without forcing
an install?

Note that I put an icon in the "User's Program Menus". Is there a special folder
for a menu item all user's can see without a reinstall?

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You might be able to create some sort of an "autoexec" batch file for all new users that will be executed when they first login. Their first login would then execute that batch/script file and install all the things you want to have installed.

Comment: I think the issue is that I create "auto run" entries in HKCU that are not copied to the new user's HKCU entries. This triggers an installation repair. Is the HKCU "folder" populated from some template when a new user is created? Pl. advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've installed an [advertised shortcut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367548(v=VS.85).aspx).  You may want to reconsider how you've architected your features/components/key files, and where you've placed advertised shortcuts.

regarding:

> Note that I put an icon in the "User's
>   Program Menus". Is there a special
>   folder for a menu item all user's can
>   see without a reinstall?

Try:
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Comment: Won't this trigger a reinstall also? I guess the real question I'm asking is if .msi repair is actually the *intended* way new users are configured for already installed products. In other words, am I trying to defeat a feature because I perceive it as an error. Pl. advise. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're seeing the attempt to reinstall because you're using an advertised shorcut.  Can you make it non-advertised?  I obviously don't know your application, but I don't see why there must be a relation between advertisement and user-specific settings. Have you considered using the HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT Registry key?  Those Registry settings are applied to any new user created post-install. Or the "C:\documents and settings\default user" directory?  Items in there are copied to all users created post-install.  It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: According to Raymond Chen (http: //blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx),
HKEY_USERS\.Default is actually the registry settings for
Local System. My question stands. I would like to install
a registry entry not using SysPrep for a template user that propagates values into HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run when that new
user is created. Thanks.

Comment: If this is a must for every user, how about creating the entry in HKLM\Software\Microsoft...

If this is a setting that can be customized by users, write your app so that it first checks HKCU.  If the HKCU entry doesn't exist, it uses the one at HKLM.

Comment: For many registry entries, that would be a viable tactic. For "Run" entries, I would end up with two auto run programs running at the same time. So there is no "default user" registry subkey that is read/write by any standard user? "No" is okay. I just don't know enough about the Windows registry subkeys to know that it's not there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The described behaviour also occurs when an installation package is run for **all users** but there are componenets which can only install **per user**.

Windows Installer detects this and upon launching the installed application from a different user automatically runs the MSI package again (quite the feature wouldn't you say?)

This problem should be reported as an error by any decent tool when validating the resulting MSI. The validation rule ICE38 partly covers this:

> Validates that components installed under the user's profile use a
>   registry key under HKCU as their key path.

There are many other validation rules which should help prevent such issues. See the [ICE Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/ice-reference) for additional info.

If no tool is at hand to check for such issues, you should be able to get a copy of Orca from the [Windows Dev Center website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe). It allows checking existing MSI packages and also allows for modifications within the MSI tables.

Comment: I know, I'm about 10 years late on this but I ran in the same issue and this was the only question which addresses the issue. I hope my answer will help other troubled souls...